# How to handle different JSON Responses from same source in flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart, parsing, json-api-response-converter

I have a flutter application retrieving a list/or anything for that matter at some point, and if there's any issue with the request, a different response is received. 
For Example:

```
{
  "status" : "success",
  "message":
    [
      {
        "updated_on" : "2022-01-09 14:26:07"
      }
    ]
}
```

For Failure:

```
{
  "status" : "error",
  "message" : "Query not found"
}
```

Using [quicktype.io](https://app.quicktype.io/), I have created class as below:

```
class ResponseList {
  ResponseList({
    required this.status,
    required this.message,
  });

  String status;
  List<dynamic> message;

  factory ResponseList.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => ResponseList(
        status: json["status"],
        message: List<dynamic>.from(json["message"].map((x) => CLASSNAME.fromJson(x))),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "status": status,
        "message": List<dynamic>.from(message.map((x) => x.toJson())),
      };
}
```

Now, the problem is, on failure, this raises an exception when i try to call `ResponseList responseAllFromJson(String str) => ResponseList.fromJson(json.decode(str));`  where the exeption says 
 `[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>'`.

I want to have a method that checks the status first, whether success or failure and then parses the remaining of the json (in `message`) or parses the whole json and returns appropriate response (text in case of failure and list of objects in case of success). 
Note: I want a reusable code, so that I can pass the response to the method and retrieve it from any point in my application. For example:

```
static bool responseStatus(dynamic response) {
    if (response != null) {
      if (responseListFromJson(response).status.trim().toLowerCase() == 'success') {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
```

Presently, above raises exception on failure but works smoothly on success.

Comment: CLASSNAME is just to convert the `List<dynamic>` to appropriate `List<CLASSNAME>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this way while parsing.

```
class MainResponse {
  String status;
  dynamic message;

  MainResponse({this.status, this.message});

  MainResponse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    status = json['status'];
    if(json['message'] is String)  {

      message = json['message'];
    }else {

      message = <Message>[];
      json['message'].forEach((v) {
        message.add(new Message.fromJson(v));
      });

    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['status'] = this.status;
    if (this.message != null) {

      if(this.message is String) {
        data['message'] = this.message;
      }else {
        data['message'] = this.message.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
      }
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Message {
  String updatedOn;

  Message({this.updatedOn});

  Message.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    updatedOn = json['updated_on'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['updated_on'] = this.updatedOn;
    return data;
  }
}
```

And call this way :

```
MainResponse mainResponse = MainResponse.fromJson(response);
```

and this :

```
 if(mainResponse.message is String) {
      var data = mainResponse.message as String;
      print('parsed String $data');
    }else {

      var list = mainResponse.message as List<Message>;
      print('parsed ${list[0].updatedOn }');
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but here is the catch, I need a usable method, means that `Message` can be anything depending upon the request, e.g. list of employees, in one request, or a list of items in another, having totally different properties. 
Also, a bit explanation on how `data['message'] = this.message.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();` is able to provide a list of `Message`.

Comment: @VAThomas : Then you have to check for every type and then return what you want. for this :  data['message'] = this.message.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();  its maping message to list from Map.

Comment: Achieved the first part, reusable code... Is it ok to assume that `data['message'] = this.message.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();` has nothing to do with the type `Message` ? BTW, thanks a ton.

Comment: @VAThomas : its okay until until you get list in message key rather then string. if you get another type of data then its creates issue as i parsed as per your current response need.